# Extract value from key-value pair in variable using Ansible regex_search

Tags: mysql, regex, ansible, jinja2

I have the following Ansible playbook which returns results from a MySQL database.

```
- name: A sample playbook to add API key to conf file
  hosts: dbservers
  become: true
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Get api key from database
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_unix_socket: "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
        login_db: sampledatabase
        login_user: root
        login_password: apassword
        query: SELECT `api_key` FROM `sampledatabase`.`apis` WHERE `servername` = '{{ ansible_host }}'
      delegate_to: "{{ hostvars[groups['dbservers'][0]]['ansible_host'] }}"
      register: api_key_value

    - name: Print api_key_value
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ api_key_value.query_result }}"
```

I get the following results.

```
ok: [rocky8.dbservers] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "api_key": "ranscharsThy8T56R"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

How do I only return the value e.g. ranscharsThy8T56R. The plan is to store this in a variable and then use Jinja templating to add to a file.

Comment: that is json so you can parse it easily